# Deleting Elements from an array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array and I want to delete the first 3 elements of the array. I tried this solution:

```
           a = np.arange(0,10)
           i=0
           while(i<3):
             del a[0]
             i=i+1
```

This gives me an error that "**ValueError: cannot delete array elements**". I do not understand why this is the case. i'd appreciate the help thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Numpy arrays have a fixed size, hence you cannot simply delete an element from them. The simplest way to achieve what you want is to use slicing:

```
a = a[3:]
```

This will create a new array starting with the 4th element of the original array.

For certain scenarios, slicing is just not enough. If you want to create a subarray consisting of specific elements from the original array, you can use another array to select the indices:

```
>>> a = arange(10, 20)
>>> a[[1, 4, 5]]
array([11, 14, 15])
```

So basically, `a[[1,4,5]]` will return an array that consists of the elements 1,4 and 5 of the original array.

Comment: @Neil: You are right. That was actually my first version, but then, for some twisted reason, I changed it to 4.

Comment: to be correct: basic slicing does not create a new array, but a new view onto the underlying data, see http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html which is one reason why numpy is as fast as C code in many cases.

Comment: @rock: Correct! I had this confused with regular Python, which does indeed create a new array.

Comment: If you want to replace the underlying data with the view, use `deepcopy` from the `copy` package` to do `a = deepcopy(a[3:])`

Answer (score 16):

It works for me:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.delete(a, k)
```

where "a" is your numpy arrays and k is the index position you want delete.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

numpy arrays don't support element deletion.  Why don't you just use slicing to achieve what you want?

```
a = a[3:]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can convert it into a list and then try regular delete commands like pop, del, eg.

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
l = list(a)
l.pop(3)
l
>>[1, 2, 3, 5]
```