# How to add or remove a specific element from a numpy 2d array?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, numpy-ndarray

Given the following numpy array:

```
arr = np.array([
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9]
])
```

delete and return:

```
arr = np.array([
    [1,2,3],
    [4,6],
    [7,8,9]
])
```

I want to delete 5 from this array. or delete arr[1][2] only. When I am using  `del arr[i][j]` it throws the following err.  `ValueError: cannot delete array elements` and numpy documentation is not clear on this case for me.

Similarly how to add an element to some rows in the same array?

To be specific, When I am reading an image with opencv I am getting this err.

`rgb_image = cv2.imread("image.png")`

`del` operation gives me the top error and I couldnt make it with `np.delete(...)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting Elements from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139425/deleting-elements-from-an-array)

Comment: What are you expecting after delete operation? A flattened array with 8 elements or a 3x3 array where deleted element is replace with 0 or another placeholder value?

Comment: this is not a 2d array and I dont want to delete a column or a row entirely. Only specific element should be deleted.

Comment: Doesn't matter, the answer is there: it doesn't support, you need to slice

Comment: slice seems too slow and takes a lot of memory!

Comment: @unlut it is a 2D array. I updated the question.

Comment: Will you do multiple operations for each array?

Comment: This deletion does not make sense with a 2d array,  You can delete like this with a list of lists, not arrays.

Comment: @AtleKristiansen yes thousands. delete is the last one. thats why I had to vectorize the image.

Comment: What means, for an image, that a value is deleted? can't you assign that value to None instead?

Comment: Note that the result will not be an array, as the amount of elements per row will not be constant, so you might aswell use lists for this

Comment: @yatu that was a worthy comment. thanks.

Comment: Print the second `arr`

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to do this, but have you considered using a [masked array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html)? You can still use most of NumPy functionality "as if" the value was not there.

Comment: @jdehesa thnks for sharing the link. I am applying seam carving on some images. I am vectorzing the image and operations for performance. when I want to delete the seam, if became problematic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A numpy array (`ndarray`) is [quote](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.1/reference/arrays.ndarray.html):

> An ndarray is a (usually fixed-size) multidimensional container of items of the same type and size.

So you cannot have rows of different lengths if you want to use the `ndarray` data structure (with all of its optimizations).

A possible workaround is to have an array of lists

```
>>> arr=np.array([
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9],
    []
])
```

(note the empty row to escape the ndarray datatype)

so you can delete an element from one of the lists

```
>>> arr
array([list([1, 2, 3]), list([4, 5, 6]), list([7, 8, 9]), list([])],
      dtype=object)
>>> arr[1]=np.delete(arr[1], [1], axis=0)
>>> arr
array([list([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 6]), list([7, 8, 9]), list([])],
      dtype=object)
```

Comment: Generally operations on an object dtype array are slower than on the equivalent nested list.  And `np.delete` is much slower than the list `del`.  `np.delete` turns its input into an array (if not already), and returns a new array.

Answer (score 2):

I think the one way would be to cast np.array to list and repeat cast to np.array, like this:

```
arr = arr.tolist()
arr[1].pop(1)
arr = np.array(arr)
```

Edit:
It seems to be right, numpy way:

```
np.delete(arr, [4, 4])
np.split(arr, [3, 5, 9])
```

Edit2:
Doesn't seems to be less time consuming, but you could check this way:

```
arr =  np.empty(3, dtype=np.object)
arr[:] = [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]
arr[1].remove(5)
```

Comment: This is expensive. This is an operation on an image, imagine this has to be repeated by width*height*100 times.

Comment: I see, maybe you can use np.delete like that: new = np.delete(arr, [4, 4]), and then somehow split to list elements.

Comment: what does split do here?

Comment: I use that because after using np.delete i've got flatten, 1d array. Just to get 2d representation again.

Comment: that is too expensive!! cannot use it. :(

Comment: I don't think that it is expensive. How you measure performance?

Comment: hardcoding doesnot work. its an image with a lot of operations on 3-4 dimensions.

Comment: What do you mean by hardcoding? I show you only an example you can easily transfer this into the function. You just have to initialize your array with np.empty(size, dtype=np.object), to make it more flexible. In this case yours inner elements are lists, not numpy.ndarrays and now you can change size of them without any problem.

Comment: `arr[:] = [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]` and `np.split(arr, [3, 5, 9])`

Comment: you can easily transfert it into function as i said, examle split: `np.split(arr, [(i*size) - 1 if(index in range((i-1)*size, i*size)) else i*size for i in range(1, size)])`, index is an index to remove, in yours example it was 4 (index of 5 element). And size is just `arr.shape[0]`.

Comment: And also as i mention line `arr[:] = [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]` is only for initialization. If you read your image array only you should do that, before preprocessing... So in yours case it would be `arr[:] = im.read(path) #or something like that`

Comment: `arr.tolist()` is quite fast.

Answer (score 1):

First convert the Array into a list using
**new_list = list(old_array)** function.(This will create a list of arrays)

Now,you can perfome all the operations of list like **pop,filter,** etc to remove whatever elements you want.

Finally when you have your filtered list, convert it back to array using

**new_array = np.array(new_list)** .(This new array will retain the dimensions of old array)